# When going to another activity Android app crashes

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to populate the `TextViews` of the second event using an `SQLite` DataBase. When the user clicks on the item from the `ListView` he/she can view the details of the event on the second `Activity` however whenever I click on an event it crashes.

MainActivity.java

```
  myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor myCursor = (Cursor) myList.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String pickedString = myCursor.getString(1);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EventDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("name_var", pickedString);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

DBHelper:

```
public ArrayList<String> getEvent(String name)
{
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from events WHERE name='" +name+"'", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EVENTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
    array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EVENTS_COLUMN_DATE)));
    array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EVENTS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));
    array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EVENTS_COLUMN_TIME_START)));
    array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EVENTS_COLUMN_TIME_END)));
    array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EVENTS_COLUMN_ADDRESS)));
    array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EVENTS_COLUMN_POSTCODE)));

    return array_list;
}
```

EventDetails.java

```
public class EventDetails extends Activity {

private DBHelper mydb;
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_title);
TextView time_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_time_date);
TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_description);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name_var");

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    ArrayList<String> valuesFromDb;
    valuesFromDb = mydb.getEvent(name);

    title.setText(valuesFromDb.get(1));
    time_date.setText(valuesFromDb.get(2));
    description.setText(valuesFromDb.get(3));


}
}
```

Comment: Always Post Logcat if app crashes

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_title);
> TextView time_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_time_date);
> TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_description);
> ```

You're calling `findViewById()` too early and get NPE here because the activity won't have a `Window` before `onCreate()`.

Move these initializations to `onCreate()`.  Also add a `setContentView()` before them where you set a layout that contains views with these ids so that non-null values are returned and you don't get NPE when trying to invoke `setText()`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong :
(The view isn't created yet)

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_title);
TextView time_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_time_date);
TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_description);
```

Correct way :

```
Private TextView title ;
Private TextView time_date ;
Private  TextView description ;
```

Then on your OnCreate after the setContentView()

```
title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_title); 
time_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_time_date);
description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_description);
```

I would suggest you to use ButterKnife for view Injection :

https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/